# Is Surah Ya-Sin/یس the heart of Quran?

Tags: quran, surat-yasin

**Is Surah  یس (Ya-Sin) the heart of the holy Quran?**

Perhaps it is considered as a famous sentence or belief that Surah Ya-Sain as Surah 36 of the holy Quran counted as the heart of the noble Quran. I can remember that someday I saw it as a hadith from Imam Jafar-al-Sadiq (a.s.), but I am not certain if he said that. In other word, I am looking for the source of this famous sentence that

> Surah Ya-Sin is considered as the heart of the holy Quran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                                  In the name of Allah
```

There are several narrations from both Shia and Sunni that Surah Ya-Sin is counted as the heart of the holy Quran.

On the whole, Surah Yasin is considered as the heart of the holy Quran because there is a hadith from the apostle of Allah (peace be upon him and his household) that said:

> «لکل شی ء قلب و قلب القرآن یس»
>
> There is a heart for everything, and the heart of the Quran is Surah
>   Ya-sin.

Besides, there are similar narrations from other Ma’soomin (infallibles) By the Prophet (peace be up on him and his household) side as well. For further information refer to the reference below.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=212898)

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him His Family and Companions)

> عَنْ أَ أَنَسٍ، قَالَ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِنَّ لِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَلْبًا وَقَلْبُ الْقُرْآنِ يس وَمَنْ أَقَرَأَ يس كَتَبَ اللَّهُ لَهُ بِقِرَاءَتِهَا قِرَاءَةَ الْقُرْآنِ عَشْرَ مَرَّاتٍ ‏"‏

Narrated Anas:
that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

**"Indeed for everything there is a heart, and the Qur'an's heart is Ya Sin. Whoever recites Ya Sin, then for its recitation, Allah writes for him that he recited the Qur'an ten times."**([Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/631230))

There is another Narration showing significance of Surah Yasin

> "‏ اقْرَءُوا ‏{‏ يس ‏}‏ عَلَى مَوْتَاكُمْ ‏"

Narrated Ma'qil ibn Yasar:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said: **Recite Surah Ya-Sin over your dying men**. This is the version of Ibn al-Ala'([Sunan Abi Dawud](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/21/33))

*Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.*